# Why is the lifetime of an object "that is the complete object of a subobject" extended when the subobject is returned?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, temporary-objects

I am studying the extension of the lifetime of a temporary when bound to a `const &`, and I would like to understand the following case:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char const * foo()
{
    std::string s("tmp");
    return s.c_str();
}

int main()
{
    char const * const & p = foo();

    // Why is the lifetime of the std::string extended in the following line,
    // rather than just the lifetime of the char* itself?
    std::cout << p; // This prints 'tmp' in VS2013
}
```

As noted, in Visual Studio 2013, the code builds without error and the console prints `tmp`.

This seems odd to me because the object whose lifetime is being extended is a *subobject* of an object local to the function being called that is destroyed when that function is exited.  There is no `std::string` on the stack as the return value whose lifetime can be extended by the compiler when it compiles the `main` function - there's just a `char *` return value, whose lifetime can be extended but which would be a dangling pointer.

But clearly, the lifetime is being extended!

The closest question I have found to this is here: [Does "T const&t = C().a;" lengthen the lifetime of "a"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689463/does-t-constt-c-a-lengthen-the-lifetime-of-a) ... However, in this question, the code `B const& b = A().b;` references the complete object `A` on the stack inside the calling function, so that object is *available* to have its lifetime extended.

As noted, it seems to me that the object whose lifetime should be extended in my code sample is a `char *`, not the string to which the `char * points`.  (That is to say, I would think the return value, being just the size of a `char *`, would itself have its lifetime extended, but that it would become a dangling pointer.)

I do not understand how it is possible for the lifetime of the `std::string` to be extended in the sample code above.  Can someone explain why this satisfies the criteria of having the `std::string`'s lifetime extended by the `char const * const &`, rather than just having the `char *`'s lifetime extended?

Comment: How is it clear that the lifetime is being extended?

Comment: The lifetime is not extended, and you are experiencing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Well, lets be glad that your cat didn't catch fire. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Pradhan because the value is available in memory at the line `std::cout << p;` and because the compiler builds without error.  However, I'd be pleased to find out that this is nonetheless not standard-compliant code.

Comment: None of those observations preclude UB.

Comment: @Zeta - I'm pleased to hear that.  It seems to me it should be undefined.  I suppose it's only obvious to me in retrospect that it's just coincidence the data is still present in memory in the `cout` line.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: `char * ptr = new char[100]; std::strcpy(ptr, "Hello, burning cat!"); delete[] ptr; /*oh oh*/ std::cout << ptr; /* the cat survived?! nope.*/`. However, being undefined behaviour, this snippet might or might not print, crash, or dispose household items into the abyss.

Comment: @Zeta I became hung up on `The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5689588/368896, but it's obvious to me only in retrospect that this doesn't apply in my case.

Comment: Sure, the reference binding extended the lifetime of the temporary, which is the returned pointer; it doesn't extend the lifetime of the pointee.

Comment: The worst part of undefined behaviour is the `seems to work` part.

Comment: And, in fact, in debug mode (in which memory is filled with special bytes when it is deleted) I get garbage.  Thank you, everyone, for taking the time to make the obvious a bit more obvious.

Comment: It would appear that no real function in the generated binary gets called (even internally) on `std::cout << p;`. This could be the reason the string prints correctly. Is it the case?

Comment: @Mints97 I assume the string is printed correctly in Release mode because - although the memory to which the pointer points has been freed - nothing has yet overwritten the bytes that were stored there.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: yes, precisely, but I believe that could happen only if no function in the generated binary is called on `std::cout << p;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about following the constructor and destructor of your object

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class string_like: public std::string {

public:
  string_like(const char* str): std::string (str) {
    std::cout << "string_like() : \n";
}
  ~string_like() {
    std::cout << "~string_like(): \n";
}
};

char const * foo()
{
  std::cout << "in foo(){} : \n" ;

  string_like  s("tmp");

  std::cout << "leaving foo(){}" << "\n";
  return s.c_str();
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << "begin main()\n";
  std::cout << "calling foo() :" << "\n";
  char const * const & p = foo();
  std::cout << "after calling foo() :\n";
  std::cout << "still in main\n" ;
  std::cout << p << "\n"; // print using g++
  std::cout << "leave main()\n";

}
```

I got the following output by g++ :

```
begin main()
calling foo() :
in foo(){} : 
string_like() :
leaving foo(){}
~string_like():  object is destroyed here
after calling foo() :
still in main
tmp    
leave main()
```